# Can someone tell me why I get an OpenGL stack underflow?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I wrote this code:

```
   void drawWinningScreen(GL10 gl) {



        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();



        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        font.setTopColor(1, 1, 0);
        font.setBottomColor(1, 0, 0);
        font.spaceString("You win", 0f, 0f, .7f, .7f, -0.15f, gl);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        int error = gl.glGetError();

    }
```

I think it should work, but it seems to be causing a stack underflow somewhere.

Comment: Which line is causing the problem? Copy a glError statement after each command and check where it happens

Comment: Count the number of `glPushMatrix` and `glPopMatrix` in your code (not just in this one function)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It was because the method has the side effect of setting the matrix mode to GL_PROJECTION.  Code after it was expecting the matrix mode to be GL_MODELVIEW.